# pagemenu-navigation Right bar button item(cannot hide according to tabs)

Tags: ios, objective-c, tabs

I am using pagemenu view in my ios app by follwing this https://github.com/uacaps/PageMenu

In a menuviewcontroller I am having a navigation bar in which at left side I have slidemenu button and right side I have bar button item(called select photo which I added in storybord)

Below that navigation bar I am adding pagemenu view 4 tab( contains patient, EMR, chat, prescription)

so according to tapping I want to hide/show that bar button item(that means only for EMR tab I want to show the bar button item(select photo) otherwise I want to hide( for remining 3 tabs),but I cannot achieve it
this is my code in that menuviewcontroller viewdidload method[image]

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad]; 


    SWRevealViewController *revealViewController = self.revealViewController;
    if ( revealViewController )
    {
        [self->_slideOutMenu setTarget: self.revealViewController];
        [self->_slideOutMenu setAction: @selector( revealToggle: )];
        [self.view addGestureRecognizer:self.revealViewController.panGestureRecognizer];

    }

    self.navigationController.navigationBar.shadowImage = [[UIImage alloc] init];
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage alloc] init] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor whiteColor]};



    UIStoryboard* sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main"
                                                 bundle:nil];
    Patient* controller1 = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"patient"];

    controller1.title = @"PATIENT";

    EMR* controller2 = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"emr"];

    controller2.title = @"EMR";
    Chat* controller3 = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"chatViewcontroller"];

    controller3.title = @"CHAT";

    Prescription* controller4 = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"prescription"];

    controller4.title = @"PRESCRIPTION";

    NSArray *controllerArray = @[controller1, controller2, controller3, controller4];
    NSDictionary *parameters = @{
                                 CAPSPageMenuOptionScrollMenuBackgroundColor: [UIColor colorWithRed:60.0/255.0 green:169.0/255.0 blue:128.0/255.0 alpha:1.0],
                                 CAPSPageMenuOptionViewBackgroundColor: [UIColor colorWithRed:255.0/255.0 green:255.0/255.0 blue:255.0/255.0 alpha:1.0],
                                 CAPSPageMenuOptionSelectionIndicatorColor: [UIColor whiteColor],
                                 CAPSPageMenuOptionBottomMenuHairlineColor: [UIColor colorWithRed:70.0/255.0 green:70.0/255.0 blue:70.0/255.0 alpha:1.0],
                                 CAPSPageMenuOptionMenuItemFont: [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:12.0],
                                 CAPSPageMenuOptionMenuHeight: @(70.0),
                                 CAPSPageMenuOptionMenuItemWidth: @(120.0),
                                 CAPSPageMenuOptionCenterMenuItems: @(YES)
                                 };

    _pagingMenuView = [[CAPSPageMenu alloc] initWithViewControllers:controllerArray frame:CGRectMake(0.0, 42.0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height-38) options:parameters];
    if (_currentIndex >= 0 && _currentIndex <= 2){


        [_pagingMenuView moveToPage:_currentIndex];

    }
    [self.view addSubview:_pagingMenuView.view];

}
```

see the screen shot i attached

so i want to hide that right navigation bar button for all tabs except emr tab 
the viewdidload and viewwill appear methods in menuviewcontroller is called only once , those are not calling every time tapping the menus(patient, EMR, chat, prescription) so i donnot know how to acheive it
please any one help me on this

thanks in advance

This works for me as accepted answer in this question

Adding this line

```
pagingMenuViewController.delegate=self;
```

after the object (pagingMenuViewController) intiated like below

```
  pagingMenuViewController = [[CAPSPageMenu alloc] initWithViewControllers:controllerArray frame:CGRectMake(0.0, 42.0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height-38) options:parameters];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.tintColor=[UIColor clearColor];

      pagingMenuViewController.delegate=self;
```

and i added this delegate 
CAPSPageMenuDelegate
ansd delegate methods

```
- (void)didMoveToPage:(UIViewController *)controller index:(NSInteger)index {
    if(index ==1){
        [self show];
    }else{
        [self hide];
    }
}
- (void)willMoveToPage:(UIViewController *)controller index:(NSInteger)index{
    if(index ==1){
        [self show];
    }else{
        [self hide];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks to Ravi Kiran and Durai Amuthan.H

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In viewDidLoad method add

```
_pagingMenuView.delegate = self
```

then implement the delegate method

```
- (void)didMoveToPage:(UIViewController *)controller index:(NSInteger)index {
    if(index ==1){
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = //your barButton to select photo
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil;
    }else{
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nil;
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = //your barButton to reveal the slide menu
    }

}
```

Comment: I have tried that code but didMoveToPage method is not calling when I change the tab is there any othere mistakes??

Comment: did you add `<CAPSPageMenuDelegate>` to your .h file?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you are assigning the delegate property after creation of instance

```
_pagingMenuView.delegate = self
```

Rest of the hiding, showing business you may handle in the delegate methods

Answer (score 1):

@sathya chinnasamy its just nothing. You may use NSNotificationCenter to here.

// paste this code your navigation bar class

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self selector:@selector(playerStatus:) name:@"hideNavigationButton" object:nil];

- (void) playerStatus:(NSNotification *) notification
{
// hide navigation button.
}

//When you tap the button call this method

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]postNotificationName:@"hideNavigationButton" object:nil];
```